# Logical implication and valid arguments question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The following is a valid argument: $[[p \lor (q\lor r)]\land \neg q] \rightarrow (p\lor r)$. Determine the rows of the table crucial for assessing the validity of the argument and which rows can be ignored.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
p & q & r & \neg q & q\lor r & p\lor(q\lor r) & [[p \lor (q\lor r)]\land \neg q] & p\lor r \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \underbrace{0}_{\text{premise 2}} & 1 & \underbrace{1}_{\text{premise 1}} & 0 & \underbrace{1}_{\text{conclusion}} \\
\end{array}
$$

So rows 2, 5, and 6 are crucial for assessing the validity of the argument, since we have the premises and conclusion $1$ in these rows.

---

Following this exercise are some questions I have, as the text I'm using  doesn't really cover these details.

1. $[[p \lor (q\lor r)]\land \neg q] \rightarrow (p\lor r)$ is also a tautology. Is it necessary that an implication of the form $$(p_{1}\land p_{2} \land \dots \land p_{n})\rightarrow q$$ to be a tautology in order to be a valid argument -- is this correct?
2. So in this exercise, only rows 2,5, and 6 assessed the validity of the argument. So for the other rows, the argument is invalid. But how can the exercise state $[[p \lor (q\lor r)]\land \neg q] \rightarrow (p\lor r)$ as a valid statement? Doesn't it depends on the values of the premises and conclusion being 1?
3. What does it take for premises to logically imply a conclusion? Must it be that the implication be a tautology? or must it be that the rows by which the premises and conclusion be 1?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Did you type the 'argument' verbatim? I ask because $[[p \lor (q\lor r)]\land \neg q] \rightarrow (p\lor r)$ is not what one would call an argument, but a statement. And judging by your use of premise 1 and 2, I'd assume the argument is $p\lor q\lor r, \neg q\models p\lor r$.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, sorry I edited it now.

Comment: You didn't replace all the instances of 'argument', still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @GitGud I copied 'argument' verbatim. It's the word used in  Grimaldi's Discrete and Combinatorial mathematics. I'm confused as to when premises logically imply a conclusion -- is it when the implication is a tautology? or is it for when the rows are 1's in their premises and conclusion?

Comment: It's kind of an abuse of language. In mathematics, when we ask "does $P \implies Q$", we're really asking "is $P\implies Q$ true?". When the implication is a tautology, that corresponds to "if and only if".

Comment: @WilliamStagner So for rows 2,5,6 in this exercise, I can say that $(P_{1}\land P_{2})\Rightarrow Q$? Otherwise, not. Is this correct?

Comment: If $P$ is true, then $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true regardless of the truth of $Q$. So, in the truth table, you only need to check that $Q$ is true when $P$ is. Also, note that it doesn't make sense to say "when" $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true. That's another artifact from the colloquial usage.

Comment: @H_T I was having trouble believing the book refers to $((p \lor (q\lor r))\land \neg q) \rightarrow (p\lor r)$, but I was able to find a few pages of the book online and this seems to be the case. This is a huge abuse, $((p \lor (q\lor r))\land \neg q) \rightarrow (p\lor r)$ is a statement, it's not argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the above comment; we have to say that the question must be rephrased as :

> show that : "if $p∨(q∨r)$ and $¬q$, therefore $(p∨r)$" is a *valid* argument.

But as you say in 1) :

> $\varphi_1, \varphi_2,\ldots,\varphi_n \vDash \psi$ **iff** $\vDash \varphi_1 \land \varphi_2 \land \ldots \land \varphi_n \to \psi$.

Thus, the "procedure" of truth-table verification used to establish the *validity* [i.e. "tautologuesness"] of the conditional it is enough to show the *validity* of the corersponding argument.

For 2), the definition of *valid* argument is "formalized" with the relation of *logical consequence* that, for propositional logic is :

> $\Sigma$ *tautologically implies* $\tau$ (written : $\Sigma \vDash \tau$) iff every
>   truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Sigma$ and $τ$ that satisfies every member of $\Sigma$ also satisfies $τ$.

Here the set of premises $\Sigma$ is : $\{ p∨(q∨r), ¬q \}$, while the conclusion $\tau$ is $(p∨r)$ and the truth table show that in all rows where **both** premises are true, also the conclusion is.

Thus, the conclusion is *tautologically implied* by the premises, i.e. the argument is *valid*.